# How do I reference a frameset within an iframe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frames

Can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong (besides using frames that is :-P).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cols = the_set.cols; //works within frameset.html
    var cols = frames['set_iframe'].the_set.cols; // doesn't work within parent
    var cols = document.getElementById('set_iframe').the_set.cols; // doesn't
    var cols = document.getElementById('set_iframe').getElementById('the_set').cols; // doesn't
</script>

<!--parent.html-->
<iframe id="set_iframe" name="set_iframe" src="frameset.html">

<!--farmeset.html-->
<frameset name="the_set" id="the_set" cols="180,*">
    <frame id="left" name="left">
    <frame id="right" name="left">
</frameset>
```

Comment: Since framesets are deprecated since HTML5 i don't know if you still want to use them.

Comment: Want or not is not the question, legacy application, trying to migrate them into an iframe so as to have the ability to put content in the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var cols = frames['set_iframe'].contentWindow.document.the_set.cols;
```

Comment: For some reason frames['x'] is returning null while document.getElementById('x') gives me the object. However .contentWindow.document doesn't seem to be working. Can one not reference iframes via frames[]?